# Geoserver WFS datastore postgis - submission hanging when there are multiple polygons / points

Tags: postgresql, leaflet, gis, postgis, geoserver

I have an web application in PHP / Symfony that communicates with the geoserver in order to submit and retrieve points and polygons. The geoserver communicates with a postgresql database, where it saves the points and polygons through WFS.

I had my geoserver in an older version (1.8snapshot) and server (ubuntu16),and now i migrated to a new server (ubuntu22), and took the opportunity to bump geoserver version to 1.21.

The problem i'm having is related with these WFS communications. When i draw a polygon in my web map application and it is submitted to the geoserver via WFS (both polygon and respective points), it works when it's just one or two with a few points. But when i draw more and more polygons and points in bigger quantities (and it doesn't need to be that more, 3 polygons with 20 points each will be enough to make it crash), the tomcat java process hangs forever and consumes a lot of CPU (100% basically) and it stays like this forever (or until i restart tomcat service). The process I'm talking about is the one that runs in "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java". If i use only 1 or 2 polygons with a few points, those processes finish and don't hang. But after a certain amount of points/polygons, it never finishes and hangs forever.

Could anyone please provide feedback on how to solve this problem? It's important to mention that i didn't had these problems before the migration.

Thank you advance for your help and attention

i tried to change jvm memory configurations, and wfs layers bounding boxes, but nothing made it work. Not sure if i've done it the right way though.

geoserver logs:

```
06 007 15:07:42 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:42 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:42 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: district_code. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: district_code. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: district_code. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: municipality_code. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: municipality_code. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: municipality_code. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lat. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lat. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lat. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lng. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lng. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: lng. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosLayer. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosLayer. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosLayer. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosDrone. Checking if containing type declares a single particle.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosDrone. Performing lookup by ignoring namespace
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [xsd.impl] - Could not find declaration for: ortosDrone. Creating a mock element declaration and parsing anyways...
06 007 15:07:42 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: polygon TransactionEventType[PreInsert]
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "fid","process_id","step_id",encode(ST_AsBinary("polygon"), 'base64') as "polygon","type","plantusage","updatedat","estimatedquality","name","obs","photofilenames","datefeature","timefeature" FROM "public"."polygon" WHERE 0 = 1
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting fid to 0
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 0 to 0
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting process_id to 80
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 1 to 80
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting step_id to 4467
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 2 to 4467
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting polygon to POLYGON ((-8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785, -8.37948650121689 40.62797562068675, -8.379218280315401 40.628065190187066, -8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785))
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 3 to POLYGON ((-8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785, -8.37948650121689 40.62797562068675, -8.379218280315401 40.628065190187066, -8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785))
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting type to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 4 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting plantusage to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 5 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting updatedat to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 6 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting estimatedquality to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 7 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting name to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 8 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting obs to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 9 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting photofilenames to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 10 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting datefeature to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 11 to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting timefeature to null
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 12 to null
06 007 15:07:42 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
06 007 15:07:42 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Inserting new feature: INSERT INTO "public"."polygon" ( "process_id","step_id","polygon","type","plantusage","updatedat","estimatedquality","name","obs","photofilenames","datefeature","timefeature" ) VALUES ( 80,4467,ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785, -8.37948650121689 40.62797562068675, -8.379218280315401 40.628065190187066, -8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785))', 4326),null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null)
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('"public"."polygon"', 'fid')
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT currval('public.polygon_fid_seq')
06 007 15:07:42 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: polygon TransactionEventType[PostInsert]
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:42 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: transaction
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = https://dummy_ip_replaced/geoserver/
    group[0] = wfs:insert=net.opengis.wfs.impl.InsertElementTypeImpl@a0b8307 (feature: [SimpleFeatureImpl:polygon=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: fid<fid id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=0, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: process_id<process_id id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=80, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: step_id<step_id id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=4467, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: polygon<polygon id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=POLYGON ((-8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785, -8.37948650121689 40.62797562068675, -8.379218280315401 40.628065190187066, -8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785)), SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: type<type id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: plantusage<plantusage id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: updatedat<updatedat id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: estimatedquality<estimatedquality id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: name<name id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: obs<obs id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: photofilenames<photofilenames id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: datefeature<datefeature id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: timefeature<timefeature id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null]], handle: null, idgen: <unset>, inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null)
    insert[0]:
        feature[0] = SimpleFeatureImpl:polygon=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: fid<fid id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=0, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: process_id<process_id id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=80, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: step_id<step_id id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=4467, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: polygon<polygon id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=POLYGON ((-8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785, -8.37948650121689 40.62797562068675, -8.379218280315401 40.628065190187066, -8.379416763782503 40.62822397218785)), SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: type<type id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: plantusage<plantusage id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: updatedat<updatedat id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: estimatedquality<estimatedquality id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: name<name id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: obs<obs id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: photofilenames<photofilenames id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: datefeature<datefeature id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: timefeature<timefeature id=fid-1445e9d5_18a6ac13515_-7e00>=null]
        idgen = GenerateNew
        inputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
    releaseAction = ALL
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
06 007 15:07:42 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
06 007 15:07:42 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" took 400ms
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - Exporting FID=[polygon.1587]
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT count(*) AS gt_result_ FROM (SELECT * FROM "public"."polygon" WHERE ("fid" = '1587') LIMIT 1000000) gt_limited_
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - _Id is abstract
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = https://dummy_ip_replaced/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [ polygon.1587 ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = polygon
    outputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
    resultType = results
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.xsd] - building schema for schema: http://opengeo.org
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - Exporting FID=[polygon.1587]
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "fid","process_id","step_id",encode(ST_AsBinary("polygon"), 'base64') as "polygon","type","plantusage","updatedat","estimatedquality","name","obs","photofilenames","datefeature","timefeature" FROM "public"."polygon" WHERE ("fid" = '1587') LIMIT 1000000
06 007 15:07:43 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" took 63ms
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - dummy_ip_replaced "POST /geoserver/wfs?" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "https://dummy_ip_replaced/step/execute/4467" "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" 
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 007 15:07:43 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 007 15:07:44 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 007 15:07:44 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
06 009 15:09:43 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
06 009 15:09:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'opengis_net_wfs_link jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
06 009 15:09:43 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for opengis_net_wfs_link: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-27.1.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.1.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
06 009 15:09:44 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: points TransactionEventType[PostDelete]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to software development. Ask the vendor!

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Hi @IanTurton i've followed what you suggested but there aren't any relevant information in the logs related to the problem i'm having